# SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here when extending superclass

Tags: javascript, syntax, super

> I have a super class School with properties name,level, and number of students

```
class School{
      constructor(name,level,numberOfStudents){
        this._name = name;
        this._level = level
        this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents
      }
      get name(){
        return this._name;
      }
      get level(){
        return this._level
      }
      get numberOfStudents(){
        return this._numberOfStudents
      }
    }// end School() class
```

> But when I extend that to a subclass PrimarySchool...

```
    class PrimarySchool extends School{
      constructror(name,numberOfStudents,pickupPolicy){
        super(name,'primary',numberOfStudents)
        this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
      }
      get pickupPolicy(){
        return this._pickupPolicy
      }
    }//end PrimarySchool
```

> I get SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here. But I should be able to pass in 'primary' as the value for the parent class property *level*. Same with name and numberOfStudents. Even If I declare *level* in the sub-class constructor and don't even pass in a value, I get the same error:

```
class PrimarySchool extends School{
  constructror(name,level,numberOfStudents,pickupPolicy){
    super(name,level,numberOfStudents)
    this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
  }
  get pickupPolicy(){
    return this._pickupPolicy
  }
}//end PrimarySchool
```

Comment: `constructror`.

Comment: You misspelled `constructor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the `constructror` in the `PrimarySchool` class. The correct word is `constructor`. Here's a working sample code:

```js
class School{
      constructor(name,level,numberOfStudents){
        this._name = name;
        this._level = level
        this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents
      }
      get name(){
        return this._name;
      }
      get level(){
        return this._level
      }
      get numberOfStudents(){
        return this._numberOfStudents
      }
    }// end School() class 
    

   class PrimarySchool extends School{
      constructor(name,numberOfStudents,pickupPolicy){
        super(name,'primary',numberOfStudents)
        this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
      }
      get pickupPolicy(){
        return this._pickupPolicy
      }
    }//end PrimarySchool


const school = new PrimarySchool( 'NY School', 2137, true );

console.log( school );
```

Do you use any IDE with syntax highlighting or a linter (e.g. ESLint)?

Comment: I do, but the CodeAcademy text editor I'm working with doesn't have any syntax highlighting. Thanks anyway lmao. Man. ugh. oof.

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions; they should be closed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was a typo too :)